# unable to upload file & image in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm learning node js & express js in tutorial point in that course i tried to upload the document but whenever i tried it shows error as"Cannot read property 'file' of undefined" pls help me to fix this problem.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require("fs");

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer  = require('multer');
var upload=multer({ dest: '/tmp/'});

// app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));


app.get('/test', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile( __dirname + "/" + "/public/index.html" );
})

app.post('/file_upload', function (req, res) {

    console.log(req.files.file.name);
    console.log(req.files.file.path);
    console.log(req.files.file.type);

    var file = __dirname + "/" + req.files.file.name;
    fs.readFile( req.files.file.path, function (err, data) {
        fs.writeFile(file, data, function (err) {
            if( err ){
                console.log( err );
            }else{
                response = {
                    message:'File uploaded successfully',
                    filename:req.files.file.name
                };
            }
            console.log( response );
            res.end( JSON.stringify( response ) );
        });
    });
})

var server = app.listen(8081, function () {

    var host = server.address().address
    var port = server.address().port

    console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)

})
```

Comment: not sure `var file = __dirname + "/" + req.files.file.name;` this mean `file` is a file which include the path ?

Comment: I've a doubt on this line fs.readFile( req.files.file.path)  i'm not sure whether we've to declare the file path in this line. If it so can u send me the syntax.

Comment: try: remove this `var file = __dirname + "/" + req.files.file.name;` and use `req.file` instead of `req.files.file`

Comment: Thanks for ur reply but it doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

Your code has multiple Problems:

1. You are not using multer (`var upload`) to handle the file upload
2. You are using the wrong variable name on `res`
3. your upload path may be wrong

I have corrected these issues and upload works now.

Also check:

- make sure you have created dir `tmp` in your working directory
- your html form needs to have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` set
- the name of the form upload element must match (e.g. `<input type="file" name="myfile">`)

---

```js
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    var fs = require("fs");
    var path = require("path")

    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var multer = require('multer');
    var upload = multer({dest: 'tmp/'});

    // app.use(express.static('public'));
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));


    app.get('/test', function (req, res) {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + "/" + "/public/index.html");
    })

    app.post('/file_upload', upload.single("myfile"), function (req, res, next) {

        console.error(">>>", req.file)

        console.log(req.file.originalname);
        console.log(req.file.path);
        console.log(req.file.mimetype);

        var file = __dirname + "/" + req.file.originalname;
        fs.readFile(req.file.path, function (err, data) {
            fs.writeFile(file, data, function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    var response = {
                        message: 'File uploaded successfully',
                        filename: req.file.originalname
                    };
                }
                console.log(response);
                res.json(response);
            });
        });
    })

    var server = app.listen(8081, function () {

        var host = server.address().address
        var port = server.address().port

        console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)

    })
```

---

```html
<form action="/file_upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="myfile">
    <button type="submit">senden</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Dr. hund its working fine. Can u help me to learn node js